# Which features are required from a heat-shrink sleeve for a tennis racket?

Tags: tennis, racket, grip

My grip size is 12cm 4 6/8 and I have a racket 4 3/8 with overgrip i.e. 4 4/8. It is not fit enough and getting some pain with it. I want to increase its size by 1/8 inches but which kind of Heat-shrink sleeve should I use? Can I buy it from any warehouse store or does it need to be tennis-specific? What kind of features are required from the heat-shrink sleeve?

[image]

*P.s. the picture is a little bit misleading but when I press the ruler to my hand: the distance from the top of my ring finger to the second crease is 12cm.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally don't recommend a heat-shrink sleeve because it's a rather "permanent" solution to your problem. If you find that the heat-shrink sleeve doesn't solve your problem you're out the cost of the heat-shrink plus the time and energy it takes to get it on/off.

Instead, just try adding a second overgrip - you can put the second overgrip either under the replacement grip (directly against the grip pallet of your racquet) or just wrap two overgrips around (on top of) the replacement grip. I would give that a try first before going to the heat-shrink sleeve.

Comment: Ha +1, Agree! This is what I actually do now and the two overgrip method is under testing! The thing is that it is a pretty soft but it feels better getting a slightly better grip particularly with topspins. With more power and topspin, the racket acts far better now, not feeling like hurting or wobbling.